# Проблема при composer install/update laravel, на windows docker wsl2

Tags: windows, laravel, docker, wsl2

Поднял докер, поднял проект, для того что бы проект работал быстрее, перенес весь проект в папку `wsl$`, и далее при `composer install` либо `update`, выдает:

```
[RuntimeException]
  File at "/WSL.LOCALHOST\UBUNTU-22.04\home\myproject\projects\project.docker\vendor/sebastian/type/src\NullType.php" does not exist, check your clas   
  smap definitions
```

Подскажите, кто как исправлял?